# Return the relative complement of two int arrays in java

Tags: java

I wish to find the relative complement of two integer arrays in java.
Suppose arr1=(1,2,4,5,3,8) and arr2=(0,-1,2,9,9,9,3,0,0),
I want my method to take the two arrays as input and return an array of all values in arr1 that are NOT in arr2, which would be (1,4,5,8).
I want the result as an int[] array as well, returned (not just printed).
Any assistance will be appreciated.

```java
class GFG{
    static void relativeComplement(int arr1[], int arr2[],
                                             int n, int m) 
    {
     
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < n && j < m) 
        {
         
            // If current element in arr2[] is
            // greater, then arr1[i] can't be 
            // present in arr2[j..m-1]
            if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) 
            {
                System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
                i++;
         
            // Skipping smaller elements of
            // arr2[]
            } else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j]) 
            {
                j++;
         
            // Equal elements found (skipping
            // in both arrays)
            } 
            else if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) 
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
         
        // Printing remaining elements of
        // arr1[]
        while (i < n){ 
            System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }    
    }
     
    // Driver code
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int arr1[] = {3, 6, 10, 12, 15};
        int arr2[] = {1, 3, 5, 10, 16};
        int n = arr1.length;
        int m = arr2.length;
        relativeComplement(arr1, arr2, n, m);
     }
}
```

Comment: The simplest would be to use an ArrayList<Integer> to store the elements of interest, then if you want to stream the array, you can stream it while mapping it to a primitive integer and call toArray(). Else, you can create a new int[] with the same size as the ArrayList and transfer the elements one by one

Comment: of course, you will need a method that can __return__ an int[] first

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Thank you for the response. I have thought of ArrayList too, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Do you happen to have a sample to share?

Comment: please elaborate on why you haven't been able to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little crude, but using hints from @experiment unit 1998x suggestions above, this is what I came up with. It works alright, I'm not sure about optimality though. Is there a way to make it cleaner?

```java
 public static int[] relativeComplement(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) { //Finds all elements in arr1 but not in arr2
        ArrayList<Integer> interest = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            int toCheckValue = arr1[i];
            boolean test = false;
             for (int element : arr2) {
                if (element == toCheckValue) {
                    test = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (test!=true){
                interest.add(arr1[i]);
            }

        }

        int[] myComplement = new int[interest.size()];
        Arrays.setAll(myComplement, interest::get);

        System.out.println("MyComplement "+Arrays.toString(myComplement)); //printing out to see if it's correct
        return myComplement;
    }
```